# Find the length of $CE$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> In quadrilateral $ABCD$, $AB=6$, $\angle{ABC}=90°$, $\angle{BCD}=45°$ and $\angle{CAD}=2\angle{ACB}$. If $DE$ is perpendicular to $AC$ with $E$ on side $BC$, Find the length of $CE$.

Could someone give me a hint? Since I can't find any equal side I can't using Law of Sines to find angle of the triangle so it's hard to find $CE$

[Picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udGpg.jpg)

Comment: If you let $x$ be the measure of $\angle ACB$, then you can express every angle in the picture in terms of $x$.  Then you can express the length of many of the segments in terms of trig functions of $x$ and $90-x$ and $2x$ and so on.  Maybe you can get a decent equation out of all that(?)  Also the two triangles $ABC$ and $ECF$ are similar (where $F$ is the intersection point in the middle.)

Comment: @B.Goddard i already tried that one. But I can't find any relation to find $CE$ at all. I also extend $AB$ meet $CD$ to get right isosceles triangle too

Comment: @user635988 where is this question from? Do you know the answer to the problem?

Comment: @ONGSEEHAI the answer is 12. Using some $tan$ and will get the answer. And this question is on the web that my teacher got. Then he solve it by himself. I'm pretty sure it is from Facebook group since he usually send the problem from that group to the students

Comment: @ONGSEEHAI I'm still waiting for someone solution tho hahahha

Comment: @ONGSEEHAI I'm sorry what do you mean by that I can't understand hahah

Comment: @ONGSEEHAI yub we do not know

Comment: @ONGSEEHAI at first I thought about that too haha, but after seeing my teacher solution I was like wow. He constructs a new height $MH$ in triangle $MEC$. Than try finding $MC$ and $MA$. And yes both of them have constant value and depending on other side. Than using $tan(2x)$ and $tan(45-x)$ we are done

Comment: @ONGSEEHAI ohh sorry my bad. $M$ is the intersecting point of $AC$ and $DE$

Comment: @ONGSEEHAI I dun know if it is polite to ask for your email here. But if you dun mind you could tell me your email. I'll send the answer. It is too long so it's hard for me hahaha. Also I'm not good at Latex too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We start from how the figure is drawn.

(1) Put C at (0, 0). (2) Draw the line L: y = –x such that L inclines $45^0$ to the negative x-axis. (3) Draw the line H: y = 6 such that it cuts the positive y-axis at Z. (4) Reflect C about H such that C’ is at (0, 12).

[image]

(5) Let A be any point on H and in the 3rd quadrant. (6) Let B be the projection of A on the x-axis.
After Joining AC and AC’, we have (i) $\angle BCA = \angle CAZ = \angle ZAC’$; (ii) AZ is the perpendicular bisector of CC’.

(7) The point of intersection of L and AC’ is D which meets the requirement of the question. (8) Let CD cuts H at Y. Then $\angle CYZ = \angle ZYC’ = 45^0$.

(9) Let the perpendicular from D cut AC at M. DM produced will cut BC at E.

[Note: It does not matter where A is. As long as it is on the negative part of H and on the far left of M will meet the given requirement.]

The question is:- "will EYC’ be collinear?". If yes, then CE = 12 because $\triangle ECC'$ is then right and isosceles.

Comment: Nice solution but quite hard for me hahahah

Comment: @user635988 I have added a picture and hope that helps.

Comment: ohh thank you that helps a lot

Answer (score 1):

[image: diagram]
Let $AB=a$, $BC=b$.

Following Mick, let $A=(-b, a), B=(-b, 0)$, $C=(0, 0)$, $C'=(0, 2a)$. Then line $CD$'s equation is $y=-x$ and line $AC'$'s equation is $y=2a+\frac{ax}{b}$. These lines intersect at $D$.

Let $P$ be the foot of the perpendicular from $D$ to $BC$.

Then $D$ is $(-y, y)$ where $y=CP=DP$ and

\begin{align*}
y &= 2a-\frac{ay}{b}\\
\implies by &= 2ab-ay\\
\implies (a+b)y &= 2ab\\
\implies y &= \frac{2ab}{a+b}
\end{align*}

Then because $DE\perp AC$, $\angle EDP=\angle ACB$, so right-angled triangles $ABC$ and $EPD$ are similar, so
\begin{align*}
\frac{EP}{DP} &= \frac{AB}{BC}\\
&= \frac{a}{b}\\
\implies EP &= \frac{a\cdot DP}{b}\\
&= \frac{a\cdot2ab}{b(a+b)}\\
&= \frac{2a^2}{a+b}\\
\implies CE&=CP+EP\\
&=\frac{2ab}{a+b}+\frac{2a^2}{a+b}\\
&=\frac{2a(a+b)}{a+b}\\
&=2a=12.
\end{align*}